# Github как правильно устанавливать и пользоваться пакетами

Tags: javascript, php, github, npm, установка

Здраствуйте, подскажите, как правильно пользоваться GitHub?
Через npm умею устанавливать пакеты, а как их правильно подключить к проекту не могу понять. В качестве сервера использую OpenServer.
Было бы замечательно, если бы расписали пример подключения любого пакета к проекту с самого начала.

Comment: Это написано в инструкции к нужному вам пакету и к GitHub не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: Я делаю все по инструкции, но допустим не могу понять, почему не работает допустим import from vue модуля.

Comment: Значит вы на самом деле делаете что-то не по инструкции. А что вы делаете на самом деле - это уж вам виднее

Answer (score 0):

У себя закинул node в папку modules

Долго разбирал , **как** окончательно дефолтные пути NPM перенести в нужную мне папку,

Я не могу написать в комментах, сами понимаете). ,  но чтобы не было потерь и лишних работы, воспользуйтесь which npm , where node из пакета OpenServera

В финале, в хардкором случае пакеты npm, node , и сам npm придется переустанавливать с помощью **yarn**

А Guthub - это, в смысле, источник приложений и исходных кодов, в вашем случае? Node - сам по себе сервер. OpnServer,NPM, GitHub это как вместе в вашем вопросе связано?